# Powershell where-object -notlike

Tags: powershell

If I pipe to `where-object { $_.someProperty -notlike "*someValue*" }`, the `-notlike` seems to filter more than just matches, but also objects whose `someProperty` is empty.

`where-object -notlike` from TechNet:

`Specifies the Not-Like operator, which gets objects when the property value does not match a value that includes wildcard characters.`

Based upon the definition, why does `-notlike` not return objects whose `someProperty` is empty? Since, no match is found?

Just to clarify:
I am performing `Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property MemberOf,someotherstuff,someotherstuff | where-object { $_.memberof -notlike "*somepartialdn*" }`

The expectation is to have the computer object returned, since there is no match, even if a property value is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on your definition of "empty".

If `someProperty` doesn't have a value, it's effective value is `$null`. Your string comparison doesn't apply to `$null`.

If `someProperty` is an empty string (`""` or `[String]::Empty`) instead, the string comparison applies.

```
$values = "indonesia","turkmenistan",$null,"columbia"
$values |Where-Object {$_ -notlike "*istan"}
# Results in @("indonesia","columbia")

$values = "indonesia","turkmenistan",[String]::Empty,"columbia"
$values |Where-Object {$_ -notlike "*istan"}
# Results in @("indonesia","","columbia")
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but if I perform -notcontains, the object whose someProperty is null (a gettype() returns something other than string) is still returned as "someProperty:   {}" So, why would -notcontains return something where -notlike does not?

Comment: Because `-notcontains` apply to the entire collection, even though it might be empty. `-notlike` only applies to the individual strings inside the collection, but if the collection is empty = no applicable value to test against

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but you may be able to get around it by doing the following:

`where-object { $_.someProperty -ne "" -and $_.someProperty -notlike "*someValue*" }`

I'm pretty sure what you are experiencing is due to the data being piped as a string... and so the empty values are taken as `""`